# heroku migration, getting could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have run the following commands:

```
git remote add mdd2 git@heroku.com:dmstaffing.git
git push mdd2 master
```

But when I try to now run

```
heroku run rake db:migrate --app mdd2
```

I get

```
rake aborted!
could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "ec2-184-73-250-226.compute-1.amazonaws.com" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5632?

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I also see:

```
g$ heroku open --app mdd2
Opening mdd2... done
durrantm.../mdd$ libprotobuf ERROR third_party/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:123] Can't parse message of type "in_memory_url_index.InMemoryURLIndexCacheItem" because it is missing required fields: (cannot determine missing fields for lite message)
^C
durrantm.../mdd$
```

could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "ec2-184-73-250-226.compute-1.amazonaws.com" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5632?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a database addon?
https://addons.heroku.com/